# jQuery UI sortable items that I used for my page doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I tried to put s sortable item as grid in my page but it appeared as just plain numbers, please tell me the reason.

```
<div class="demo">

<ul id="sortable">
<li class="ui-state-default">1</li>
<li class="ui-state-default">2</li>
<li class="ui-state-default">3</li>
<li class="ui-state-default">4</li>
<li class="ui-state-default">5</li>
<li class="ui-state-default">6</li>
<li class="ui-state-default">7</li>
<li class="ui-state-default">8</li>
<li class="ui-state-default">9</li>
<li class="ui-state-default">10</li>
<li class="ui-state-default">11</li>
<li class="ui-state-default">12</li>
</ul>

</div>
```

and I pasted the script and style tags from jQuery like this in the head :

```
<style>
#sortable { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
#sortable li { margin: 3px 3px 3px 0; padding: 1px; float: left; width: 100px;     height: 90px; font-size: 4em; text-align: center; }
</style>
<script>
$(function() {
    $( "#sortable" ).sortable();
    $( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();
});
</script>
```

Comment: Check your console, does it give you any errors? Did you include jQuery and jQuery UI?

Comment: there's no errers and I yes I did. So what's the solution?

Comment: This works as expected: http://jsfiddle.net/L2aAW/ . You may have some missing styles.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are missing the CSS files. Make sure you have included the `jquery-ui-x.x.x.css` file.  The sorting function is working fine, so it looks like a matter of presentation

I added the CSS from Google CDN and it looks fine now

```
<link rel="Stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.6/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
```

You may also want to remove the `float: left` from your css so they appear as a list